# Creating DTOs using select conditionally

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Linq query in the following way, where if some value becomes null within from, then avoid the select, if its not null or has value then only make the select, in the below query select should happen only if vv is not null and items that are being selected should not be null

```
var Violations = from vv in n.Violations
select new
{
    ViolationNumber = vv.ViolationNumber,
    ViolationId = vv.ViolationId,
    inspectionItemNum = (inspectionItems != null && inspectionItems.Count() > 0)
        ? (from i in inspectionItems
           where i.Violations.Any(v => v.ViolationId == vv.ViolationId)
           select i.InspectionItemNumber)
        : null
}
```

So in the above Linq query, if the vv becomes null, if vv becomes null, it should just return null, I don't want select new to be executed as it is going to throw exception, how can I handle this situation in C#, any help please? - thanks a lot.

Comment: it's not to see what inspectionItems is, a Query, a List, ....
Consider using a Join instead of this "Any".
Isn't your ViolationId Unique ? Do you expect to have more than one ID per Table ?
"Find" might be more appropriate than "Any".

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want a null entry in the new collection if the Violation isn't in the inspectionItems Violations collection (as well as in n.Violations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So in the above Linq query, if the vv becomes null, (...) it should just return null

Answering the comment, you can use the ternary operator in the select (to preserve the null values in the result):

```cs
var Violations = from vv in n.Violations
          select vv != null
               ? new { /* ... */ }
               : null;
```

... or if you want to filter out the vv which are null:

```cs
var Violations = from vv in n.Violations
          where vv != null
          select new { /* ... */ };
```

---

**Old answer** (seems that I haven't understood you correctly)

If I understood you correctly, you can do the select only if the `n.Violations` is not null:

```cs
var Violations = n != null && n.Violations != null
        ? from vv in n.Violations
          select new { /* ... */ }
        : null;
```

Comment: Sorry, how can I check if vv itself becomes null? Its giving vv as null, so any option for that please?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Writing the answer I haven't thought about the `null` elements present in the list.